# help with math in R

Tags: r, math, statistics, plot

Need help to plot graphs:

Wt contains 1000 Iterators on how far one has walked the 100 steps. Mean and sd are the mean and standard deviation of those 1000. I am asked to create five graphs showing from the starting position to the end position after a hundred steps with time t on the x-axis and the status of the y-axis. t is 100.

Can someone explain and show how to plot graph like that?

Code for Wt:

```
 Wt = NULL
    for(i in 1:1000){
        Xk = rnorm(100,mean=0.4,sd=0.7)
        Wt[i]=sum(Xk)
    }

    mean(Wt)
    sd(Wt)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
matplot(replicate(5,cumsum(rnorm(100,mean=0.4,sd=0.7))),type="l")
```

Comment: i would like to get some explanations, what does cumsum and replicate do?

Comment: @David But this is so pure... (-;

Comment: @endif `?cumsum` `?replicate`

Comment: But how can i mark my axis like set "Time" text under x-axis and "Status" at y-axis?

Comment: @endif `matplot(<other things>,xlab="X-axis title",ylab="Y-axis title")`

Comment: @endif: I think you would benefit from reading an R graphics introduction like http://gbi.agrsci.dk/statistics/courses/phd07/material/Day1-R-Intro/basic-graphic.pdf or http://csg.sph.umich.edu/docs/R/graphics-1.pdf

Also look into ggplot2, which has a deep- and sanely-structured syntax and produces beautiful graphs.

Comment: take a look at '?par' for setting the labels of axis. However, this really sounds like a homework problem and I don't like to solve your homework problem. Does your professor know about this?

Comment: This is homework and i was just looking for some help and hoped someone could explain how i plot those graphs. My Professor only tells me to google or try to convert my matlab knowledge (which i dont have because i took java class instead og matlab), so the only way to get help and tips seem to be over the internet and I came here to get some tips and help. It would have been enough to get info about ?cumsum or these links gsk3 sent in. but mbq decided to give me a solution so I apologize if i was wrong to come here and try to get some help.

Comment: @endif: It's okay to ask for help with homework provided you follow the guidelines; see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info.  In particular, be upfront that it is homework, and ask for help only on the part you're stuck with, not the whole assignment.